# Я могу (и) разозлиться

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы, и, частицы

Можно ли здесь ставить "и" и какую роль она выполняет, если поставить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‟И” в данном случае это частица, и она выполняет следующую функцию. Представим ситуацию: школьник А бросает бумажки в школьника Б, тем самым дразня его, а школьник Б говорит: ‟Я могу и ударить”. Частица ‟и” делает угрозу более мягкой, указывая на то, что человек не хочет переводить конфликт в острую фазу, а предпочёл бы, чтобы его собеседник прекратил некое нежелательное поведение. Носитель языка понимает, что вариант без частицы имеет большую вероятность перевести конфликт в некую острую фазу, где он будет исполнять угрозу. То есть использование частицы ‟и” в такой ситуации это примерно как сказать: я угрожаю, но предпочёл бы, чтобы ты не вынуждал меня исполнять угрозу; в то время как вариант без частицы это просто угрожающий ультиматум — либо перестань, либо я сделаю это.
Возьмём ваше предложение и какой-нибудь контекст для него. Например, есть сельский житель Василий, у которого сосед Степан ворует помидоры. Василий заметил это, а потом при встрече говорит: ‟Степан, я могу и разозлиться”. Если Василий скажет: ‟Я могу разозлиться”, то это сразу переводит ситуацию в конфликт, а если он говорит: ‟Я могу и разозлиться”, то это более мягкий вариант угрозы: Василий угрожает, но указывает, что он предпочёл бы, чтобы Степан просто перестал воровать помидоры и конфликт разрешился мирно.

Я могу разозлиться = Либо перестань, либо я исполню угрозу.
Я могу и разозлиться = Я угрожаю, но предпочёл бы, чтобы вы прекратили это поведение и конфликт разрешился бы мирно.

**Дополнение к ответу на тему: почему здесь ‟и” не ровно ‟даже”.**
Слово ‟даже” используют тогда, когда хотят указать на высокую меру чего-то. Взгляните на примеры:

> Даже Вася справился с этой контрольной работой. (Высокая мера простоты контрольной.)
> Под лежачий камень даже вода не течёт. (Высокая мера плотности.)
> Тут даже специалист бессилен. (Высокая мера сложности задачи.)
> Я могу даже умереть. (Высокая мера риска.)
> Он не может даже писать. (Высокая мера повреждения мозга.)

В предложении в вопросе и с контекстом, который я придумал, про помидоры под разозлится подразумевается то, что Василий начнёт предпринимать какие-то ответные меры, которые сильно навредят Степану. Если Василий скажет: ‟Я начну даже предпринимать какие-то ответные меры, которые сильно навредят вам”, то это будет неправильное использование ‟даже” потому, что это не какая-то высокая мера мстительности за подобные проступки, а самый обыкновенный стандарт — ответить на плохое поведение в отношении вас. Вот если бы он ответил: ‟Я могу даже убить вас”, то это было бы правильное использование ‟даже”, так как это высокая мера мстительности за подобные действия в вашем отношении.
Вот ещё несколько примеров, чтобы объяснить это:

> После аварии он не может даже бегать как Усэйн Болт. (Неправильное использование ‟даже”, потому что тут не просто не высокая мера повреждений, а не понятно, есть ли они вообще, так как большинство здоровых людей не могут так бегать.)
> После аварии он не может даже вилку держать. (Правильное использование ‟даже”, так как это высокий уровень повреждений от нормы.)

Больше я не хочу придумывать, но я думаю, что идея понятна.

**Ещё одно дополнение к ответу:**
Если говорить о том, с какими словами пересекается в значении слово ‟и” в данном вопросе, то это ‟ведь” – ‟Я ведь могу разозлится”. И да, как я и написал в ответе, это специфическая функция этих слов для смягчения угрозы. И да, в словаре на Грамоте нет этого значения.

Comment: Прямая замена не работает одинаково (не всегда звучит удачно). Там значение "даже", хоть бейтесь головой о стену, вы не докажете, что 2+2=5. У слова "даже" много пунктов в словарях. А вы поставьте "даже" перед "начну", тогда хорошо звучит.

Comment: Если что-то звучит хорошо, то это не значит, что это не бессмыслица, которая составлена грамматически верно. ‟Даже” используется там, где есть крайне высокая мера чего-то, если этой крайне высокой меры нет, то ‟даже” носители языка не используют.

Comment: Мы не будем говорить, что это точь-в-точь "даже". Это нечто подобное. Вот здесь крайне высокая мера реакции при дружеских отношениях — злость.

Comment: Испытать злость, когда человек сделает что-то сильно неустраивающее вас, то это стандартная реакция. Если сказать: ‟Я могу даже разозлиться”, то это бессмыслица.

Comment: Нет, не нормальная, если человек хочет помочь и сделать что-то хорошее. А ему говорят: *Не лезь, я могу даже разозлиться за такую помощь.*

Comment: *Я могу за это даже разозлиться. = Я могу и разозлиться. = Я могу, представь себе, разозлиться.* Неужели здесь разный смысл?

Comment: Нет, потому что разозлится это слишком обыденно. Это не какая-то крайне высокая мера проявления недовольства.

Comment: Ладно, у "даже" сильнее значение, чем у "и". Поэтому так получается (не всё совпадает).

Comment: Ещё раз скажу: это не то же самое, это нечто похожее. Крайность есть, хоть и не высокая.

Comment: Поколебить ваше мнение в чём-то уже победа. Мне этого достаточно

Comment: У меня не мнение, а истина. Если же мнение, то так и говорю. Вы не поколебили. Вы просто пытались подкрепить свою позицию. Вы ни капли не доказали, что значения "даже" нет вообще.

Comment: "Ладно" было сказано не для согласия, а в таком смысле: *ладно, тогда попробую так*.

Answer (score 5):

"И" ставить можно: ***Я могу и разозлиться.***

В данном случае "и" – частица. В зависимости от контекста она может выполнять все три функции, указанные в Большом толковом словаре ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%98&all=x)):

> **И, *частица.*** **1.** Усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, для выделения, подчёркивания его. *И какая же ты стала слезливая.* **2.** Соответствует по зн. частицам: *тоже, также. Будет и на нашей улице праздник* (Погов.). *Все говорят: нет правды на земле. Но правды нет – и выше* (Пушкин). **3.** Соответствует по зн. частице *даже. Отец и не подозревал о переживаниях сына.*

**Примеры** из Национального корпуса русского языка:

—  *Я могу **и** постоять,  — пророкотал он, глядя на меня исподлобья.* [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Дело об убийстве, или Отель «У погибшего альпиниста» (1970)]

*― Да, теперь, пожалуй, я могу **и** прощать!* [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

*Но я могу **и** ошибаться, потому что исторический аспект меня интересует крайне мало.* [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)]

*А если Юрка с этим делом затянет, я могу **и** не дождаться.* [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139086/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 1):

Частицу И употребляют (среди прочего), когда говорят о чём-то неожиданном — здесь так. Смягчение, о котором говорит Jim Korbett, здесь слегка и лишь как следствие: раз указываем на неожиданность, то как бы и смягчаем за счёт этого. Как и во фразе: *Я могу даже разозлиться.*

Фразу "*я могу разозлиться*" (без И) можно сказать так, что это не будет звучать угрожающе.

Comment: Ну что тут можно сказать?  Это как в том случае, когда описывают слона по частям: один видит хобот, другой ноги, третий еще что-то. А здесь ЦЕЛЫЙ СЛОН с обобщенным УСИЛИТЕЛЬНЫМ значением.  Я, к примеру, не согласна даже с вашими частными вариантами. Мне видится там другой оттенок усиления. Давать третий ответ? Нет здесь НИ СМЯГЧЕНИЯ, НИ НЕОЖИДАННОСТИ.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Усиление должно в чём-то заключаться, и это можно описать. Если вы скажете просто про усиление, то вы не скажете ничего. Третий пункт словаря. "Даже" как раз передаёт неожиданность.

Comment: Хм, даже в словаре нашёл: Употр. для выражения неожиданности и интенсивности того действия, о к-ром сообщается.

Comment: Это сказано о частице "даже". А что у нас с И? **3. Соответствует по значению частице *даже*.** Что вы мне будете рассказывать? Говорю не своё мнение, а то, как оно есть на самом деле. Когда уверен на 100%. И эти пункты словаря только сейчас открыл.

Comment: А вы ПЕРВЫЙ пункт читали? Усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, для выделения, подчёркивания его. И вы опять перечисляете ОТТЕНКИ усилительного значения. ДАЖЕ. I. частица. Употр. для выделения и усиления слова или словосочетания, к которому относится.  Тоже обобщение усилительного значения.

Comment: В том примере оно нейтрально, здесь же оно никак не нейтрально по значению.

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ ответом на ваш ответ.

Comment: В разных случаях свои оттенки. Я думаю, что в заданном предложении Частица  И подчеркивает глагол как крайнюю степень негативной реакции на что-либо.

Comment: @Jim Korbett Я только что написала то же самое, не видя вашего ответе.  Но это всего лишь  частный оттенок усилительного значения.

Comment: @Sharon У частицы И есть два значения: "даже" и "вдобавок". Второе тоже возможно: *Я могу рассердиться. Я могу и разозлиться.* Смотрю, что в начале предложения она может быть нейтральной.

Comment: Вам же написали в ответе: в зависимости от КОНТЕКСТА. В заданном предложении частица И находится в середине предложения и относится к глаголу.  О частном значении усиления в этом предложении я уже написала. Что нам еще обсуждать.

Comment: В БТС что-то только в первом пункте сказано об усилении. В первом пункте слово нейтрально, нет значения. Здесь же явно есть значение. Но это уже теория: можно ли считать усилением то, что в других пунктах...

Comment: Первый пункт интересен. Похоже, что это возможно только тогда, когда частица стоит в начале предложения. Иначе она не будет нейтральной.

Comment: @Sharon Вот как этот первый пункт представлен в словаре Ушакова (недавно наткнулся): употребляется для усиления выразительности в начале восклицательного предложения; в начале вопросительного предложения для усиления вопроса, его выразительности, близко по значению к "неужели". В словаре есть примеры. То есть употребляется в начале простого предложения. В других позициях значение "тоже" или "даже".